# Ajax reloading the same page, with 2 javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok so I have a bit of a problem. I am using a template home page. A top Navigation Bar, Side Navigation bar and a `"#Content_Area"` div

To avoid loading and reloading tons of standard JS libraries

```
bootstrap-datepicker.js,
bootstrap-editable.min.js,
bootstrap-wizard.min.js,
bootstrap.min.js,
docs.min.js,
jquery.min.js,
moment.min.js,
rowlink.js,
select2.min.js + all the css
```

each time a user just navigates to a different page (that use the same exact template) I am just reloading the content area with jQuery     .load() function. It works perfectly, with some cool    fadeIn() and    fadeOut() effects on loading (which I really like).

Say a user goes to Link A. That loads the contents of    A.jsp

Then goes to Link B. That loads the contents of    B.jsp

So far so good, the Major Problem is if he goes back to A and A has some custom Javascript. The browser created a temp js file    1.js (confirmed with Firebug) then on the second visit (the page did NOT reload at all) it created a second temp file    2.js containing exactly the same code, resulting in nothing working on the second visit.

How do I get rid of those temp files when emptying the div?

Comment: you can't unexecute javascript, you'll have to code around knowing that it will happen.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the temp file appears in http://localhost:8888/js/jequery.min.js/eval/seq ... so I suppose I need to flush that folder while emptying and reloading the content area div

Comment: ok, so how do I check ,for example, if an element has been initialized or has an onclick event attached to it ??

Comment: When you attach the event to it, add a class to it. If it has the class, then don't attach another event. Or, unbind the event prior to binding. If it doesn't have the event, unbinding will simply do nothing.

Comment: Well it worked !! having a class and using $(".class").remove() on all conflicts and re initiating everything in their custom code did the trick ... however the temp files are growing rapidly ... in 30 mins usage session had about 70 temp files ... dont know when will this hit a limit and blow up ... ofcourse a refresh is the easiest solution but it sounds very unprofessional ... wish I could garbage collect those files :) ... post it as an answer and explain for others and I ll accept it